# C1ReportViewer printing cutting off bottom of each page, Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, printing, componentone

I am having a problem with C1ReportViewer. when I go to print. each page gets about 1/2 the last row and the page number cut off. it is like it want to print all the way to the bottom of the page. I have been playing with some of the properties in C1Reportviewer. but nothing seems to help.
thanks
Danny

Answer (score 1):

The ComponentOne.com user forum is the best place to ask this question.  I have used it many times and they are quick to respond.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the [latest](http://prerelease.componentone.com/dotnet30/c1wpfreport/2013-t3/C1WPFReport_3.6.20133.54660.zip) build of the control and see if you still face any issues.

Also, is there any difference in te report's page size and the pagesize of the default printer on your system? 
A suggestion in such a case is to set the '[UsePrinterResolution](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1report/C1.C1Report.4~C1.C1Report.C1Report~UsePrinterResolution.html)' property of C1Report to False.

In case the issue still persists, you may post the issue at [C1Forums](http://our.componentone.com/groups/forum/xaml/studio-for-wpf/) and it would be taken care of.

Regards,
Mohita